# Unable to copy a component on the same page in CQ5

Tags: components, aem

Once the component is placed and filled with content, it cannot be copied>pasted to another place. There is no option to copy the component, which means, that the component has to be deleted and created and filled with content from scratch.
Please help as i am really stuck with this. Please guide as to what i am really missing out in this.

Answer (score 2):

In your component, create a node named `cq:editConfig` with `jcr:primaryType` as `cq:EditConfig`

Save and add following property to this node - 
`cq:actions` type is multivalued String and property values as `edit, insert, copymove, delete`

Look at '/libs/foundation/components/mvt/cq:editConfig' for reference on your local instance.

you must add `copymove` to enable the feature you are looking for.